# Keras saved model returns different result than original model using Batch Normalization on multiple GPUs (Distributed training)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu, evaluate

I got a different result when using evaluate function on a saved model when compare with the original model. This only happens when Batch Normalization is included in the model and when training on multiple GPUs with MirroredStrategy.

Here is my model

```
with strategy.scope():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
  ])

  model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Multiple GPUs with MirroredStrategy

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
print('Number of devices: {}'.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))
```

Output

```
Number of devices: 2
```

Evaluate after training

```
eval_loss, eval_acc = model.evaluate(eval_dataset)

print('Eval loss: {}, Eval Accuracy: {}'.format(eval_loss, eval_acc))
```

Output

```
79/79 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.0424 - accuracy: 0.9884
Eval loss: 0.04239395260810852, Eval Accuracy: **0.9883999824523926**
```

Save model and evaluate again

```
path = 'saved_model/'
model.save(path, save_format='tf')
with strategy.scope():
  replicated_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(path)
  replicated_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                           optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                           metrics=['accuracy'])

  eval_loss, eval_acc = replicated_model.evaluate(eval_dataset)
  print ('Eval loss: {}, Eval Accuracy: {}'.format(eval_loss, eval_acc))
```

Output

```
79/79 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0424 - accuracy: 0.9883
Eval loss: 0.04239019751548767, Eval Accuracy: **0.9883000254631042**
```

- Without BN

Output from evaluate

```
79/79 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0450 - accuracy: 0.9837
Eval loss: 0.04498908668756485, Eval Accuracy: **0.9836999773979187**
```

Save model and repeat evaluate

```
79/79 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0450 - accuracy: 0.9837
Eval loss: 0.04498908668756485, Eval Accuracy: **0.9836999773979187**
```

I have also tried with one GPU, and results from original model and saved model are the same.

These are tested on Tensorflow 2.3.1, Keras 2.4.3 and CUDA 10.1

[Code for reproduce results] (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14iv88UJwFSv1SaVzmEl9RMOa1EH8IiRG?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's written somewhere in the official Keras doc that BN layer uses 2 different modes when training and evaluating.

EDIT: Here is the [doc](https://keras.io/api/layers/normalization_layers/batch_normalization/), you can read the training and inferencing parts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also thought that and checked the document for the way BN computes during training and inference. But this issue doesn't occur with one GPU. So I suppose that the problem isn't related to these formulas. Perhaps when outputs from GPUs are combined.